# Read and write fixed length flat file using spark(SparkSQL) in java(not scala, not python)

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, flat-file

I have to implement a use case in which I have to read fixed length flat file using Spark SQL(DataFrame) in java and write to another fixed length file . My boundation is I can use only java. Can anyone suggest me a good way to implement this functinality in Java spark

Comment: You mean something like this? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

Comment: Not exactly. I have a fixed length file in which column are arranged according to some bits. Like column 1 will take 2 bit , column 2 will take 10 bits and so on. I have more than 40 columns like this

Comment: Its not a parquet file. It can be any fixed length file

Comment: Yes, but you can read by line and then split accordingly

Comment: Can you please share some example(code snippet).

Comment: @gvlachakis - can u please share some code snippet.It will be a great help